# Find the antiderivative: Polynomial over polynomial

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

$$\int \frac{x-1}{x^2 + 3x}\;dx $$

After working through it,  I arrive at

$$ \frac{1}{3} \Big(\,4\log \big( \,x+3\,\big) - \log \left(\,x \,\right) \Big)$$

Which webwork deems incorrect. Am I going wrong, here?

Comment: How did you produce that solution?

Comment: [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+%28x-1%29%2F%28x%5E2%2B3*x%29) agrees with you except for one additive constant of integration.

Comment: This solution seems  fine to me!

Comment: Consider using ln function instead of log.

Comment: $\log$ function will be between modulus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice, $$\int \frac{x-1}{x^2+3x}$$
$$=\int \frac{x-1}{x(x+3)}dx$$
Using partial fractions 
$$=\int\left( -\frac{1}{3x}+\frac{4}{3(x+3)}\right)dx$$
$$=-\frac{1}{3}\int \frac{dx}{x}+\frac{4}{3}\int \frac{dx}{x+3}$$
$$=-\frac{1}{3}\ln|x|+\frac{4}{3}\ln|x+3|+C$$
$$=\color{red}{\frac{1}{3}(4\ln|x+3|-\ln|x|)+C}$$

You need to use mode '$|\ \ |$' instead of parenthesis  '$(\ \ )$' & add a constant $(C)$ of integration in your answer

Comment: But OP said he already know to solve this!

Comment: He was unsure of his solution.  Showing the working seems reasonable to me.

Comment: The absolute value indicators were necessary. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Undisputably,

$$ \frac{1}{3} \Big(\,4\log \big( \,x+3\,\big) - \log \left(\,x \,\right) \Big)'=\frac{1}{3} \Big(\frac4{x+3} - \frac1x \Big)=\frac{x-1}{(x+3)x}.$$
WeBWorK seems wrong to tell you wrong (requirements to use of absolute values and add a constant are debatable).